# Why must an argument ever be cast to const?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constants

My understanding is that the const in an argument declaration represents that the function being declared will not change the const value. So why does this ever place a demand on the constness of the argument passed by the caller?

The defining code:

```
void Func(const Foo**);

main()
{
  Foo* fooPtr;
  Func(&fooPtr);
}
```

Visual Studio 2012 compiler yields:

```
> error C2664: 'Func' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Foo**' to 'const Foo**'
> Conversion loses qualifiers
```

But the following works:

```
main()
{
  Foo* fooPtr;
  Func(const_cast<const Foo**>(&fooPtr));
}
```

What is the underlying theory?

Comment: Don't do that. Make the parameter a proper `const Foo * const *`.

Comment: @chris: If you don't want to change the caller's pointer, then pass `const Foo*` by value. If you do, then the parameter type is fine as it is (although `const Foo*&` might be more idiomatic); it's the argument it's being called with that's the wrong type.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, That's true, it's just that `const Foo * const *` is the "const version" of what `&fooPtr` can be automatically converted to. I do agree it's probably not the best type choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the conversion were allowed, then it could be used to circumvent const-correctness:

```
const Foo const_foo;

void evil(const Foo** p) {
    *p = &const_foo; // *p is 'const Foo*', so this assignment is allowed
}

int main() {
    Foo* p;
    evil(&p);     // modifies p to point to const_foo
    p->modify();  // BOOM! Modifying a constant object
}
```

You can convert to `const Foo* const*`; that doesn't allow you to change the `Foo*` to point to anything else, so can't break const-correctness. That would be better than using a dodgy cast and hoping for the best; although you should ask yourself why you're not simply passing the pointer by value, if you don't want to change it.

Comment: Great answer and great example. I think you could improve your answer by moving your comment to Chris to the end of the answer, since it deals with the immediate case I have. In particular, my Foo* fooPtr is actually non-const, and I do indeed want to modify the pointer within Func(), while at the same time Func() promises not to modify the object itself. Your example makes clear why it is impossible for Func() to make that promise.

Comment: In my application fooPtr points to the tail of list and Func() appends a certain item to it, requiring that fooPtr be updated.I guess the best thing to do is drop the promise from the argument of Func()... unless you have (or someone else has) another suggestion. ... and Thanks!

Comment: ... although dropping the const promise from Func() means that calling Func() on a const fooPtr, will require a const_cast in the other direction... Apparently to avoid const_casts, two versions of Func() must exist! Any way around that?

Comment: When it is the case that Func() indeed modifies fooPtr, there should be two versions of Func(), one defined in terms of the other:

Answer (score 0):

When it is the case that Func(&fooPtr) indeed modifies fooPtr while leaving *fooPtr unchanged, there should be two versions of Func(), one defined in terms of the other:

```
void Func(const Foo**);
void Func(Foo** fooHndl)
{
  Func(const_cast<const Foo**>(fooHndl));
}
```

This allows Func() to be called with a handle (**) to either a const or non-const object.